# call controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

hey every one i want to call controller action using ajax. but its gives an error.
"resource cannot be found". javascript function call successfully controller action is not call

here is my view code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="EditUser('Delete', 'Users', '@Model.Items.ElementAt(i).ID');">Link</a>



 function EditUser(action, controller, id)
            {

                alert(action);
                alert(controller);
                alert(id);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Users")',
                    data: "{ id: '" + id + "'}",
                    success: function (response) {
                    if (response.d != '1') {
                        alert('Not Saved!');
                    }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                    if (response.responseText != "") {
                         alert(response.responseText);
                         alert("Some thing wrong..");
                       }
                   }
                 });
            }
```

and here is my controller action.

```
public override ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
    int a = id;
     return View("Edit", DTO);
    }
```

Comment: have you declared it as a "Post" method in controller. something like [HttpPost]

Comment: no i am not declare anything

Comment: then add [HttpPost] above your declared method in controller. or Use 'Get' in ajax. It will work then .

Comment: not working after changes

Comment: are you returning `json` from the controller? which does not seem to be.

Comment: without using [HttpPost] in mehtod decalred is working but one problem it is not redirect a page..

Comment: i am returning a view

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id='Sample'></div>
Modify your Ajax function as below.
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Users")',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (response) {
            $('#Sample').html(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText != "") {
                 alert(response.responseText);
                 alert("Some thing wrong..");
               }
           }
         });

[HttpPost]
public override ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
int a = id;
 return PartialView("Edit",dto);
}
```

if you are specifying the Ajax type as post make sure to add
    [HttpPost] 
attribute in controller action.

Comment: what do you want to return from controller action? is it redirecting to another page or partial page loading.?

Comment: i am returning and i want to display this view

Comment: if you are using ajax then its like you want to load the page partially.

Comment: edited the answer you have to create a #Div to load the partial view data and make sure partial view returning the correct HTML.